# Javascript: cannot access "style" property for div elements in array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple tic tac toe game as my introduction to JS and I ran into a problem almost immediately. I have a div with the class="container", and I use JS to create 9 more div elements inside it.

I have created the div elements with and put them in the cells[] array with no problem. The problem arrises when i try to access .style from the array elements.

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const cells = [];


for (let i = 0; i < 9;) {
    cells[i] = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cells[i]);
    cells[i].onclick = function(){cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";}  //this line is where the problem is
i++;
}
```

I have gone about this using addEventHandler() too, still with me not being able to access the .style property. When I type it in it doesn't show up on that autofill thing VSCode does.

Help?

Ps. I have noticed the cells[] array can't always access it's elements when inside a block.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to how [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) work in JavaScript.

Here's a demo with your current code (plus some CSS to make it clear what's happening):

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const cells = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 9;) { // actually, the problem is here...
    cells[i] = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cells[i]);
    cells[i].onclick = function(){cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";} // ...here...
    i++; // ...and here
}
```

```css
div:not([class]) {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

div:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<container id="container"></container>
```

Note that the *next* div is always highlighted, not the one that was clicked.

Because you increment `i` within the block itself, that value is captured by the `onclick` callback, so it's always 1 higher than it should be.

Instead, you need to increment `i` within the parentheses as the third setup statement for the loop itself.

Here's the fix:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const cells = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 9; ++i) { // increment here...
    cells[i] = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cells[i]);
    cells[i].onclick = function() { cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; }
    // ...not here
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

div:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<container id="container"></container>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

for (let i = 0; i < 9; ) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  container.appendChild(div);
  div.addEventListener('click', chanegColor);
  div.classList.add('setWidth');
  i++;
}

function chanegColor() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
 .setWidth {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="container"></div>
```

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

for (let i = 0; i < 9; ) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  container.appendChild(div);
  div.addEventListener('click', chanegColor);
  div.classList.add('setWidth');
  i++;
}

function chanegColor() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```